# iOS 7 Simulator on Mac doesn't work with custom location (Also doesn't ask permission)

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, location

I'm trying to make an iOS7 app that uses the current location of the device. I'm using the iPhone simulator on my Mac, but I'm having some problems. Every time my view that the location manager is in appears, it prints out 0.000000 for both latitude and longitude, even after I've set a custom location (from simulator>debug>location).

Also, it seemed strange that the simulator didn't ask for permission to use current location when it opened the app. Anybody know what's going on here?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    _location = [locationManager location];


    _coord.longitude = _location.coordinate.longitude;
    _coord.latitude = _location.coordinate.latitude;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    _coord.longitude = _location.coordinate.longitude;
    _coord.latitude = _location.coordinate.latitude;
    printf("%f\n",self.coord.longitude);
    printf("%f\n",self.coord.latitude);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the 'live' current location with an iOS Simulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102917/is-it-possible-to-get-the-live-current-location-with-an-ios-simulator)

Comment: By default simulator location is set to None. So you need to either go to the simulator menu Debug -> Location and pick one of apple's locations or choose your own custom coordinates. You may also pick one from the console location icon in the bottom of Xcode. There you can choose famous ww locations like London or Moscow etc. You can also set your default simulator location in scheme (Edit scheme).

Comment: You're calling `[super viewDidLoad]` twice in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: You need to get the newLocation from the delegate method didUpdateLocationToLocation:fromLocation:. Also implement didFailWithError delegate method.

Comment: simplest answer, run your app on an actual iphone / iPad

Comment: @SamBudda, the answer from that referenced a solution that I mentioned already attempting. It didn't work.

Comment: @MartinKoles I mentioned that I already tried debug>location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the newLocation from the delegate method didUpdateLocationToLocation:fromLocation:. Also implement didFailWithError delegate method. It takes some time before you start getting updated locations, hence the delegate call.

The last location is usually cached, so it maybe wise to check location's timestamp and filter the old location out.

**Edit:**

This is the cleanest example I can provide. Start new project in Xcode, pick Single View application template, iPhone. Don't touch storyboard, just replace content of your ViewController.m with this and run in Simulator or device. If on Simulator, go to Debug and set some location and you will get coordinates in the console. I am also starting and stopping location updates when the view goes on or off screen.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - Location Manager delegate methods

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    if ([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow] >= -300.0) {

        NSLog(@"updated location with latitude %f longitude %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude, newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error     {
    if(error.code == kCLErrorDenied) {

        // alert user
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Access to location services is disabled"
                                                        message:@"You can turn Location Services on in Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

    } else if(error.code == kCLErrorLocationUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"Error: location unknown");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error retrieving location");
    }
}

#pragma mark - Location Manager getter

- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager
{
    if (!_locationManager) {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        _locationManager.distanceFilter = 60.0;
    }
    return _locationManager;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to try this when I get home.

Comment: When I try to overwrite didUpdateToLocation it get's mad and says "Duplicate Declaration of method 'locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation'"

Comment: That means that you already had the method didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation in your class. Your original problem is that you are trying to access the update location in a wrong method. viewWillAppear is called once just before everything is loaded and the view is going to appear on screen. But at that time your locationManager did not post any location updates yet. It takes several seconds before didUpdateToLocation is called. To resolve your original problem, just move your location print code to didUpdateToLocation, like NSLog(@"%@", newLocation); under // do your stuff in my example.

Comment: I haven't used didUpdateToLocation anywhere in my entire project but it still says there's a duplicate declaration.

Comment: I have updated my answer with full code sample, the cleanest I can provide. Also see these helpful tutorials: [http://www.devfright.com/ios-6-core-location-tutorial/](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/) or  [http://www.devfright.com/ios-6-core-location-tutorial/](http://www.devfright.com/ios-6-core-location-tutorial/)