# iOS Location Service Accuracy

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, geolocation, gps

Referring to the following snippet, what accuracy and filter value should I use to make the location detection as sensitive as possible?

Can assume that I am making a landmine detector, and the location of landmines are known. So I want to trigger the alarm as soon as the user walked into a certain zone.

Thanks a lot !

```
//Create a new location manager
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

// Set Location Manager delegate
[locationManager setDelegate:self];

// Set location accuracy levels
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer];

// Update again when a user moves distance in meters
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:500];

// Configure permission dialog
[locationManager setPurpose:@"My Custom Purpose Message..."];

// Start updating location
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: The most sensitive is kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation, but it also uses the most battery. If you skip the distance filter, you will simple get all location updates.

Comment: @MartinKoles Hey, Thanks for the comment. I need to know the location of the user of my app all the time when my app is active. So in my case, do I need to keep the location as a background process? Or I can just turn it on when my app become active ?

Comment: You just start the locationManager updates when your app becomes active or a view appear on a screen and then stop it when entering background or going off screen. See the earlier example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387574/ios-7-simulator-on-mac-doesnt-work-with-custom-location-also-doesnt-ask-permi/21388128#comment32398409_21388128

Comment: Also, Apple's documentation on accuracy, worth the check. Scroll to Accuracy Constants: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_29

Comment: @MartinKoles I see. Does it make sense if I put it in AppDelegate? So that I can activate it once the app went active?

Comment: That is fine, you can put it there if you wish. Just make sure you use only one instance of location manager.

Comment: @MartinKoles Unfortunatly from Aplle you never get all location updates: especiallay wghen you are standimng still, you does not get one, although the GPS chip would deliver one each second. Depending on the App one might want all locations.